# How to Show Code Properly In HTML with Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I making a website where I can store my python code in. I want the spaces,line breaks,indentations to show correctly on the HTML side of the page, but they are not working properly. I used the `<pre>` tag, but I gives some sort of space on the first line. This is what I get when i put the `<pre>` tags.

:[image: Python Code]

I want the first line to be vertically aligned to the if-else statement.

This is my html code:

```html
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}


{% block head %}
    <title>CodeBase | {{ code.title }}</title>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ code.title }}</h1>
    <br>

    <pre>
        {{ code.code }}
    </pre>
    

{% endblock %}
```

This is my views.py

```py
def SeeCode(request, code_pk):
    code = Code.objects.get(pk=code_pk)
    # first_line = code.code.split('\n')[0]
    context = {
        "code": code,
        # "first_line": first_line
    }
    return render(request, "base/see_code.html", context)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `<pre>{{ code.code }}</pre>`

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know it was this simple!

Comment: Do you also know how to put syntax highlighting for the code?

Comment: \`\`\`python
[code]
\`\`\`
should work

Comment: around which tag in my code?

Comment: @Suhas for syntax highlighting you would need to use some JS library (for example highlight.js which is also used by Stack Overflow)

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. You can have a look at syntax highlighter, like prism.js or highlight.js.

Comment: So, do I just copy the cdn and it will work?